# Installing Laravel - php version

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install Laravel but when creating a project with (composer /composer create-project laravel/laravel /my-path/), but I get these errors:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - laravel/framework v4.2.9 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
> - laravel/framework v4.2.8 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
> - laravel/framework v4.2.7 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
> - laravel/framework v4.2.6 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
> - laravel/framework v4.2.5 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
> - laravel/framework v4.2.4 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
> - laravel/framework v4.2.3 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
> - laravel/framework v4.2.2 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
> - laravel/framework v4.2.11 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
> - laravel/framework v4.2.10 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
> - laravel/framework v4.2.1 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
> - laravel/framework v4.2.0 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
> - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.2, v4.2.3,
>     v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
>
> Potential causes:
>
> - A typo in the package name
> - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see
>     https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion
>     for more details.

I don't understand as I'm using MAMP on Mac OSX 10.8.5 with php 5.5.3 (and also 5.2.17).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do `php -v` from the command line to see what version of PHP is actually being used by your `create-project` command

Comment: Thanks! I did it and it tells me i'm using php 5.3.28... do you know how I can change it to 5.5.3?

Comment: Can't tell you how to do it on a mac, I only use Linux (or virtual boxes running Linux)

Answer (score 1):

I updated my PHP to 5.5.3 using this tutorial: http://ziad.eljammal.com/install-php-5-5-on-mac-os-x/